# AppCenter cannot find private package when building

Tags: azure-devops, visual-studio-app-center

Trying to put together my first package in appcenter.

**AzureDevOps**

I have created 2 repos in my azuredevops account

- MyMobile.Core  (package)
- MyMobile.FirstApp (this repo references MyMobile.Core Package published automatically in my feed.)

**AppCenter**

```
- Created a build  that uses MyMobile.FirstApp repo.
```

**AppCenter building error :**

NU1101: Unable to find package MyMobile.Core
No packages exist with this id in source(s): nuget.org

What is the correct approach so that appcenter finds my package?

How do I add my private feed url in appcenter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my answer here.All I had to do is create a nuget.config

https://dev.to/muak_x/how-to-use-a-private-nuget-server-feed-on-app-center--1alf

Comment: Does this mean my project is no longer using the PackageReference feature of .NET Standard? Or are they both used in tandem to reference packages?

Comment: Where did you host your private nuget? Can we just checkin into source control in this case azure devopps and restore from there?